# error: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to String

Tags: java

I'm taking a Java class for college, and was working on some given tasks. This is the code I wrote for it.

```
public class String
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  String city = "San Francisco";
  int stringLength = city.length();
  char oneChar = city.charAt(0);
  String upperCity = city.toUpperCase();
  String lowerCity = city.toLowerCase();

  System.out.println(city);
  System.out.println(stringLength);
  System.out.println(oneChar);
  System.out.println(upperCity);
  System.out.println();
  }
 }
```

which yielded these results

```
C:\Users\sam\Documents\Java>javac String.java
String.java:8: error: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be 
converted to String
          String city = "San Franciso";
                        ^
String.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
            int stringLength = city.length();
                                   ^
symbol:   method length()
location: variable city of type String
String.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
            char oneChar = city.charAt(0);
                               ^
symbol:   method charAt(int)
location: variable city of type String
String.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
            String upperCity = city.toUpperCase();
                                   ^
symbol:   method toUpperCase()
location: variable city of type String
String.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
            String lowerCity = city.toLowerCase();
                                   ^
symbol:   method toLowerCase()
location: variable city of type String
5 errors
```

I've tried searching for an answer but I didn't really find anything that helps. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Don't call your class `String` .

Comment: rename your `public class String` to something else

Answer (score 6):

Since your class is named `String`, unqualified type reference in `String city` is taken as reference to your own class.

Either rename the class to some other name, or you'll have to write `java.lang.String` wherever you reference the "built-in" Java `String` class.

Answer (score 4):

It is conflict between system class java.lang.String and your class named String. Rename your class String to say MyString, i.e. replace line:

```
public class String
```

with

```
public class MyString
```

And rename file String.java containing this class to MyString.java.

Answer (score 0):

write one statement java.lang.String.*;
import java.lang.String; your problem will be solved

Answer (score -2):

String is a reserved key word in Java, Please refer to the reserved keywords in java [Java Reserved Keywords](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-keywords#:%7E:text=A%20list%20of%20Java%20keywords%20or%20reserved%20words,that%20can%20hold%208-bit%20data%20values.%20More%20items).

Renaming the class to something other than these keywords would be the solution to your problem. Or you can follow the import statement solution above.

BTW, Please use a good IDE to develop java programs, it seems that your IDE is not showing or linting basic rules.

Comment: Wasn’t that already covered by the other answers?

Comment: `String` is not a keyword.